# How to get NIC speed mode remotely?

Tags: c#, registry, wmi

I am trying to get NIC speed mode (100 Mb half duplex, 100 full duplex etc.) remotely.
I've found that it is possible to get NIC speed via WMI (class MSNdis_LinkSpeed).
But it is impossible to get duplex mode.

The only decision I've found to check net adapters interfaces in registry. But there are different keys in registry depends on NIC vendors.

Does anybody know any other way to get NIC speed mode remotely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See this previously posted SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489358/how-can-i-programmatically-detect-a-windows-network-adapters-duplex-state).